# Is it possible to match on Option<Vec<T>>?

Tags: types, rust, match

I'm failing to understand how I could iterate on a `Vec` of `Option`s and act only when a certain condition is met the type of the element.

Specifically, I'm working on a network application where I want to iterate over all possible IP addresses for a network interface (IPv4 or IPv6) and only do something with the v4 addresses. In this case I want to print them, so I know I have to implement `Display`.

Printing my value with the `Debug` formatter, I get:

```
Some([V6(fe80::6a5b:35ff:fec7:5eeb), V4(10.0.11.241)])
```

Which is an `Option<Vec<std::net::IpAddr>>`. I want to iterate over the vector and print every `V4` address I encounter via the `Display` implementation.

Note that [`std::net::IpAddr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/net/enum.IpAddr.html) is defined as

```
pub enum IpAddr {
    V4(Ipv4Addr),
    V6(Ipv6Addr),
}
```

How do I match the enum on type (`V4` only in my case)?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Here on SO, it is expected to put some effort into your problem first and describe what you have tried in your question. In order to avoid downvotes, you could add details to your question, like "I tried this, but it didn't work" or "I don't really understand this language feature".

Comment: "so I know I have to implement the Display method" -> it seems that you are  asking two questions or at least mixing two topics. "[...] iterate on a Vec of Options" -> in the title you said `Option<Vec<T>>`, so an optional vector, not a vector of options. How about you show us some code you wrote trying to solve your problem? Even if it's super incomplete, it probably helps us a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use std::net::IpAddr;

fn printer(addrs: Option<Vec<IpAddr>>) {
    if let Some(addrs) = addrs {
        for addr in addrs {
            if let IpAddr::V4(v4_addr) = addr {
                println!("{}", v4_addr)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For details, see [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book) sections on:

- [loops](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/loops.html)
- [enums](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/enums.html)
- [if let](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/if-let.html)
- [matching](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/match.html)

Comment: *Note*: this isn't really code that would run in production. To just print values, you would pass these values by reference.